# Chrome app and azure database connection

Tags: database, google-chrome, azure, cloud

I am developing an application that requires access to a cloud azure database for the chrome box. The application will only be running on the chrome box device.

It will be required to design the application so that a user of the device can insert, update or delete records in the database.

What is the best approach for this project?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use Azure Mobile Services to create a facade for your database that can be easily be called from an HTML app.

Check this tutorial: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-get-started/

Is it the "best" approach?  Well, you'll have to decide.